# What is the Lam for?

Tags: tafseer, arabic, surat-al-mujadilah

In Surah Al Mujadalah Ayah 3, Allah(SWT) says:

> وَالَّذِينَ يُظَاهِرُونَ مِنْ نِسَائِهِمْ ثُمَّ يَعُودُونَ لِمَا
>   قَالُوا

What is the Lam (اللام) connected to?  and what is the tafseer/meaning of "they go back to what they said"  (يَعُودُونَ لِمَا قَالُوا) ?

بماذا تتعلق اللام؟  و ما معنا عودهم لما قالوا؟

Comment: Excuse me, but I can't really understand your question. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't mean to translate the question. You asked *"What does 'they go back to what they said'"*. What is that you're asking about? Meaning? Tafseer? I'rab? Hukm?

Comment: And the Lam here is the same as "to" in the English translation. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: I am asking for Tafseer.

Comment: Good question to detailed, I think the answer is related to meaning word "يظاهرون" They relate to "ظهر" It is an expression of the Arabs during the Jaahiliyyah. I will search about it in sha'a allah in detailed and put the answer here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Eozaheron" "يظاهرون" They relate in Arabic word "zihaar" "الظهار" which is derived from "AL Zohar" "الظهر"

Were Arabs in Jaahiliyyah , if someone Zahara"ظاهر" from his wife, who told her: "You are on myself as  Zahr of my mother" "انت عليّ كظهر أمي"

And zihaar in the Jaahiliyyah  was divorce, and God making for this divorce expiation,so did not make it a divorce as Arab in Jaahiliyyah  considered it.

and in another ayah describes this meaning explicitly and clearly:

> **" الَّذِينَ يُظَاهِرُونَ مِنكُم مِّن نِّسَائِهِم مَّا هُنَّ أُمَّهَاتِهِمْ ۖ إِنْ أُمَّهَاتُهُمْ إِلَّا اللَّائِي وَلَدْنَهُمْ ۚ
>   وَإِنَّهُمْ لَيَقُولُونَ مُنكَرًا مِّنَ الْقَوْلِ وَزُورًا ۚ وَإِنَّ
>   اللَّـهَ لَعَفُوٌّ غَفُورٌ "**
>
> Those of you who divorce your wives by calling them 'mothers,' cannot
>   (make them) their mothers. Their mothers are only those who gave birth
>   to them. They surely utter what is unseemly and a lie. But God is
>   forbearing and forgiving. [58:2]

While:

> "then revoke what they had said"
>   "ثم يعودون لما قالوا"

There are several sayings and explanations for this:

- Some people said: to returning to term zihaar so repeat it, and this
  statement is invalid.
- Imam Shafei said: that is holding his wife after "zihaar" divorce
  while you can to divorce her and didn't divorce.
- And Ahmad ibn Hanbal said: is that return to intercourse or insist
  upon, is not permissible for him until expiate in this expiation.
- Abu Hanifa said: is returning to divorce (zihaar) after forbidden it
  and lift what it was is Jaahiliyyah, when man divorce (Zahir) his
  wife, he forbidden her, not bump up except  offer expiation.

The expiation is explaining in the rest of ayah:

> **" فَتَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ مِّن قَبْلِ أَن يَتَمَاسَّا ۚ ذَٰلِكُمْ تُوعَظُونَ بِهِ ۚ وَاللَّـهُ بِمَا تَعْمَلُونَ خَبِيرٌ،فَمَن لَّمْ
>   يَجِدْ فَصِيَامُ شَهْرَيْنِ مُتَتَابِعَيْنِ مِن قَبْلِ أَن يَتَمَاسَّا
>   ۖ فَمَن لَّمْ يَسْتَطِعْ فَإِطْعَامُ سِتِّينَ مِسْكِينًا ۚ ذَٰلِكَ
>   لِتُؤْمِنُوا بِاللَّـهِ وَرَسُولِهِ ۚ وَتِلْكَ حُدُودُ اللَّـهِ ۗ
>   وَلِلْكَافِرِينَ عَذَابٌ أَلِيمٌ "**
>
> should free a slave before having physical contact (with them). This
>   is to warn you, as God is aware of what you do,If one does not have
>   the means (of doing so) then he should fast for two months
>   continuously before he has physical contact; but any one who is unable
>   to do so, should feed sixty needy persons. This (is enjoined) so that
>   you may be faithful to God and His Apostle. These are the limits set
>   by God. As for the unbelievers, there is painful punishment for them.

Comment: I'm sorry for bad language, but answer directly related to Arabic ..